# Accessing username with getRemoteUser() when using custom authentication filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Short version:  How do I get `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` to return the username when I am using a custom authentication filter?

Long version:

I am modifying a Tomcat application that currently uses declarative security (web.xml & tomcat-users.xml) to instead use a custom (written by me) authentication filter (derived from javax.servlet.Filter).  There is a lot of information out there on how to do this and it looks very straightforward.

However, the existing application makes calls to `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()`, and I assume that unless I do something to set this property in my filter, it will return null.  I cannot find any information on how to populate the `getRemoteUser()` property in a filter (there is no `setRemoteUser()`).  I found a [post out there](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/how-to-set-remoteuser-td3483472.html) that recommends wrapping the request object in the filter.  I will do this if I have to, but I am hoping there is a less invasive way to accomplish this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the only way to modify an `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse` is to decorate it and provide your own implementation for the methods of interest by overriding them. This is a standard pattern with authentication filters and that is the purpose of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` (the response counterpart is `HttpServletResponseWrapper`). We do it this way to wrap a kerberized request, as follows

```
public class KerbHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    private Principal myPrincipal;
    private String myAuthType;

    public KerbHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest aRequest,
        Principal aPrincipal,
        String aAuthType)
    {
        super(aRequest);
        myPrincipal = aPrincipal;
        myAuthType = aAuthType;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the Remote User name as user\@domain.com.
     */
    @Override
    public String getRemoteUser()
    {
        return myPrincipal.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthType()
    {
        return myAuthType;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal()
    {
        return myPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks easy enough.  Sub-question:  I see you create a `Principal` and override `getUserPrincipal()`.  We do not use `Principal`s in this application.  Will I break something somewhere if we don't override `getUserPincipal()` and only override `getRemoteUser()`?

Comment: No you won't (this is my specific case for kerberos authentication). All you are interested in is getRemoteUser() and as long as you return  the value you deduced by running your authentication protocol, it's sufficient (again assuming that all your clients of `HttpServletRequest` use getRemoteUser() to get the user login).