# request.getRemoteUser returns null

Tags: java, request

I have deployed a web in tomcat 7.0.29, generate the HttpServletRequest's Object request,
when I used the request like belows:

```
 String remoteUser=request.getRemoteUser();
```

The remoteUser will be null. Any way to get remote use?

I have refered to the link
[Accessing username with getRemoteUser() when using custom authentication filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446257/accessing-username-with-getremoteuser-when-using-custom-authentication-filter) ,but cannot resolve this error...

Comment: `getRemoteUser()` returns `null` when the user is not authenticated.

Comment: Hi Noob, would you tell me how to config to get a value... I have tried but failure...

Comment: @Edward: there is some configuration required if you want all JEE security features. Check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt this issue.
1. I have used tomcat-6.0.37(x86) and IIS7(or 7.5) at the WindowServer 2008(x86) [jdk 1.6.20(x86)].
The detailed Orders Please View:
1.http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html
2.
1)http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html
2)http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html
3.http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html